# Prove that a linear mapping between vector spaces is an open mapping iff

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

Let $(N,|| \ ||)$ and $(N_1,||\ ||_1)$ be normed vector spaces and $f$ a linear mapping of $N$ into $N_1$.  Prove that $f$ is an open mapping if and only if $\forall$ $n \in \Bbb N $, $B_r(0) \subseteq  f(B_{1/n}(0))$, $\exists$ $ r \gt 0$.

I can't figure out how this would make sense.  I know that an open mapping is one whose image of each open set is open, but how can an open ball about $0$ in $N$ be a subset of the image of an open ball about $0$ in $N_1$?  Is this just saying the $0$ vector in $N$ and $N_1$?

Comment: It is saying that the image of the ball $B(0,{ 1\over n}) \subset N $ contains a ball about the origin $B(0,r) \subset N_1$.

Comment: This isn't how one writes mathematics, you can't put one quantifier at the beginning at the sentence and the other at the end! Does the sentence "For  all $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$, $B_r(0)$ is included in $f(B_{1/n}(0))$, there exists $r > 0$" make any sense? No, you write "$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \exists r > 0$ s.t. $B_r(0) \subseteq f(B_{1/n}(0))$".

Answer (score 1):

You have to show that the image of the open subset $U$ is open, let $x\in U$, there exists $n$ such that $B(x,1/n)\subset U$. Consider $r$ such that $B(0,r)\subset f(B(0,1/n)$, $B(f(x),r)=f(x)+B(0,r)\subset f(x)+f(B(0,1/n))=f(B(x,1/n))\subset f(U)$. This implies that $f$ is open.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is open then for every $n$, the set $B_{\frac{1}{n}}(0)$ is open in $N$ and so $f[B_{\frac{1}{n}}(0)]$ is open in $N_1$ and it contains $0 = f(0)$. So $0$ is an interior point of $f[B_{\frac{1}{n}}(0)]$ which means that we have some $r>0$ such that $B_r(0) \subseteq f[B_{\frac{1}{n}}(0)]$. This shows necessity of the condition.

Suppose $f$ obeys this condition, then let $O$ be any open set in $N$, and we want to see that $f[O]$ is open, so let $y$ be any point in $f[O]$. So there is some $x \in O$ such that there is some $n$ such that $B_{\frac{1}{n}}(x) \subseteq O$, because $O$ is open. Then we know that there exists an $r>0$ by the condition, so that $B_r(0) \subseteq f[B_{\frac{1}{n}}(0)]$.

If $d(y,y') = ||y - y'||_1 < r$, then $y - y' \in B_r(0)$, so $y - y' \in  f[B_{\frac{1}{n}}(0)]$, so there is some $x' \in B_{\frac{1}{n}}(0)$ with $f(x') = y - y'$. So $x - x' \in B_{\frac{1}{n}}(x)$ (as $||(x-x') - x|| = ||-x'|| < \frac{1}{n})$, so $x - x' \in O$ and so $f(x+x') = f(x) - f(x') = y - ( y - y') = y' \in f[O]$. As $y'$ was arbitrary, $B_r(y) \subseteq f[O]$ and so $y$ is an interior point of $f[O]$.

As $y$ was arbitrary, $f[O]$ is open, as required.

The idea is to use linearity and translation invariance of the norm, to transport openness around the origin to openness everywhere.